# Balancing chemical equations - Matrix determinant is zero for specific reaction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant, chemistry

I am currently working on a program which takes a chemical equation as input and returns the balanced chemical equation instead. It finds the appropiate chemical coefficients with matrix operations, using the formula $x = A^{-1}b$. I am using [JAMA](https://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) for calculations involving matrices. According to their docs, it calculates $A$'s inverse using

> Eigenvalue Decomposition of both symmetric and nonsymmetric square matrices

Let's take an example to better visualize this. Suppose the following chemical equation with denoted coefficients for every compound:

$aCa(OH)_2 + bH_3PO_4 \rightarrow cCa_3(PO_4)_2 + dH_2O$

The computer creates an equation for every element:

$P: b - 2c = 0$

$H: 2a + 3b - 2d = 0$

$Ca: a - 3c = 0$

The last equation needs to be $a = det(A)$ for three reasons. We need a square matrix (and that's why oxygen's equation is omitted) to compute it's inverse and determinant. Secondly, we need to give a numerical value to one of the variables to be able to get a numerical result, and thirdly (as far as I understood because I learned nothing about matrices in school yet) $adj(A)$ is multiplied by $1/det(A)$ to get $A^{-1}$ which causes the computed coefficients to sometimes be non-integer numbers. I am not sure of how or why setting $a$ to $det(A)$ works, neither this is the most efficient way of doing it.

$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&1&-2&0\\2&3&0&-2\\1&0&-3&0\\1&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$
$b = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\\det(A)\end{array}\right]$

After dividing every number to the GCD the computed vector $x$ will be:

$x = A^{-1}b = \left[\begin{array}{c}6\\4\\2\\12\end{array}\right]$ = $\left[\begin{array}{c}3\\2\\1\\6\end{array}\right]$

And of course, the balanced chemical equation is

$3Ca(OH)_2 + 2H_3PO_4 \rightarrow Ca_3(PO_4)_2 + 6H_2O$

This program works perfectly for even more complex equations:

$299H_2SO_4 + 10K_4Fe(CN)_6 + 122KMnO_4 \rightarrow 60CO_2 + 5Fe_2(SO_4)_3 + 188H_2O + 60HNO_3 + 162KHSO_4 + 122MnSO_4$

$9Fe_{36}Si_5 + 836H_3PO_4 + 192K_2Cr_2O_7 \rightarrow 324FePO_4 + 45SiO_2 + 128K_3PO_4 + 384CrPO_4 + 1254H_2O$

However, in the process of testing, I found a chemical equation that produces the following error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Matrix is singular.`

Let's write everything down:

$aB_{10}H_{12}CNH_3 + bNiCl_2 + cNaOH \rightarrow dNa_4(B_{10}H_{10}CNH_2)_2Ni + eNaCl + fH_2O$

$B: 10a - 20d = 0$

$C: a - 2d = 0$

$Na: c - 4d - e = 0$

$H: 15a + c - 24d - 2f = 0$

$Cl: 2b - e = 0$

This time, the code omits the equation for three elements ($N, Ni, O$) because it would result in an overdetermined system and a non-square matrix.

$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}10&0&0&-20&0&0\\1&0&0&-2&0&0\\0&0&1&-4&-1&0\\15&0&1&-24&0&-2\\0&2&0&0&-1&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$

This is completely unexpected, both for me and the script. Using a matrix calculator, I found out that $A$ has no inverse: its determinant is zero. I analyzed the matrix and found that $10a - 20d = 0$ and $a - 2d = 0$ are really
the same equation. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the matrix being singular.

What should I do to make this work? Should I use a different method for finding solutions and representing my system of equations, or do I have to do something specific when $det(A) = 0$ ? I've read a little bit about Gaussian Elimination and LU Decomposition, but I don't seem to understand them very well. In case I have to use another method for solving the system, which one is the most suitable for this script? Also, I would be happy to get some details about it if possible. Keep in mind I'm a beginner in this matrix field. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use linear programming to solve this problem.

Comment: "which causes the computed coefficients to sometimes be rational numbers." The coefficients are always rational numbers. I think you mean non-integer. "Secondly, we need to give a numerical value to one of the variables to be able to get a numerical result" I think what you're getting at is that the equations would otherwise be homogenous. Also, aren't you omitting three elements in the problem that caused the exception?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Huh? They are clearly already using linear algebra.

Comment: @Acccumulation The more general problem that I see here, is that a chemical equation of the form $$a(ABC)_m + bD_n \to c(AB)_s + d(CD)_t.$$  You've see an additional degeneracy here : the constraints on $A$ and $B$ are redundant.  You can add as many as such $A$ and $B$ artificially as you like.  It's still solvable by a human coupled with a computer algebra system, as there're around a hundred elements in the Periodic Table, but math seeks a more general answer.  If you know a little linear programming, these are called equality constraints.  Big-$M$ method/two-phase method handle this well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant is zero, because the first two lines are linearly dependent,
indeed, we can consider $B_{10}C$
as one "atomic element",
or complex, if you like, which provides just one equation,

$B_{10}C:\quad a-2d=0$,

so you need to remove the first line
and replace it with the line with $Ni$ instead,

$Ni:\quad b-d=0$.

Then $\det A=4$ and the solution is

$a=4$, $b=2$, $c=12$, $d=2$, $e=4$, $f=12$,

or, equivalently,

$a=2$, $b=1$, $c=6$, $d=1$, $e=2$, $f=6$.

And indeed,

\begin{align} 
2B_{10}H_{12}CNH_3 + NiCl_2 + 6NaOH 
&\rightarrow 
Na_4(B_{10}H_{10}CNH_2)_2Ni + 2NaCl + 6H_2O
.
\end{align}

Comment: The last line of OP's matrix is a also all 0's, which looks like a typo.

Comment: @Andy Walls: Yes, it's definitely a typo. Oh, it's already fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Not all matrices are invertible.

If your mathematical system of equations is underdeterminated or overdeterminated, your chemical equation is chemically wrong and you have to correct it.

To check if your chemical equation is correct, you have to check the rank of your matrix.

You should use an algorithm that yields the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) of your matrix, e.g. [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

You also could include electric charges in your chemical equations.